# Unix Bash - print field values matching pattern

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

Say I have this in file, (FIX Message)

```
35=D|11=ABC|52=123456|33=AA|44=BB|17=CC
35=D|33=ABC|11=123456|44=ZZ|17=EE|66=YY
```

I want to grep and print only the values after `11=` and `17=`, output like this.

```
ABC|CC
123456|EE
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This can easily be achieved with either  [`sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) or [`awk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html).

Answer (score 3):

Whenever there's name=value pairs in the input I find it useful for clarity, future enhancements, etc. to create a name2value array and then use that to print the values by name:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[|=]"; OFS="|" }
{
    delete n2v
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        n2v[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    print n2v[11], n2v[17]
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ABC|CC
123456|EE
```

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/.*\b11=\([^|]*\).*\b17=\([^\|]*\).*/\1|\2/g' file
ABC|CC
123456|EE
```

Through grep and paste.

```
$ grep -oP '\b11=\K[^|]*|\b17=\K[^|]*' file | paste -d'|' - -
ABC|CC
123456|EE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F"11=|17=" '{for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {split($i,a,"|");printf "%s|",a[1]}split($i,a,"|");print a[1]}' file
ABC|CC
123456|EE
```